# Viewing a website using window.open in HTML5 jQuery Mobile within an iOS app

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, window.open

I'm trying to open a webpage within my HTML5 jQuery iOS Mobile app within the app itself.

I'm using:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com', '_self', 'location=yes');">My Link</a>
```

However, obviously, the website opens up fully over the app with no way to close and return to the app.

Is there anyway that I can force the size of the opened weblink (to be smaller than presently) and add a 'back' link? Or can anybody suggest another (better) way to do this? I've had a good look and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my issue by using an iFrame with an outer div that had

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

applied to its CSS for scrolling in iOS.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;z-index: 9999;overflow-y:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;width:1024px;height:600px">
    <iframe style="width:1024px;height:600px" src="http://www.bbc.co.uk"></iframe>
</div>
```

Although this worked for my scenario, it may not be the best option for yours.